# Assigning variable number to complex array

Tags: fortran, complex-numbers

I want to assign complex array as variable.
My code is like

```
        complex indx(3,3)
        integer i,j

        do i=1,3
          do j=1,3
            indx(i,j) = (i,j)                
            write(*,*) indx(i,j)
          end do
        end do
```

and in this case I am getting an error like

```
 A symbol must be a defined parameter in this context.   [I]
                       indx(i,j) = (i,j)
```

Answer (score 9):

You must use function [cmplx](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CMPLX.html) to build a complex value you want to assign.

```
    complex indx(3,3)
    integer i,j

    do i=1,3
      do j=1,3
       indx(i,j) = cmplx(i,j)               
       write(*,*) indx(i,j)
      end do
    end do
```

The syntax you tried is only valid for constant literals.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Vladimir F tells the important part: for `(i,j)` to be a complex literal constant `i` and `j` must be constants.<sup>1</sup>  As stated there, the intrinsic complex function `cmplx` can be used in more general cases.

For the sake of some variety and providing options, I'll look at other aspects of complex arrays.  In the examples which follow I'll ignore the output statement and assume the declarations given.

We have, then, Vladimir F's correction:

```
do i=1,3
  do j=1,3
    indx(i,j) = CMPLX(i,j)   ! Note that this isn't in array element order
  end do
end do
```

We could note, though, that `cmplx` is an *elemental* function:

```
do i=1,3
  indx(i,:) = CMPLX(i,[(j,j=1,3)])
end do
```

On top of that, we can consider

```
indx = RESHAPE(CMPLX([((i,i=1,3),j=1,3)],[((j,i=1,3),j=1,3)]),[3,3])
```

where this time the right-hand side is in array element order for `indx`.

Well, I certainly won't say that this last (or perhaps even the second) is better than the original loop, but it's an option.  In some cases it could be more elegant.

But we've yet other options.  If one has compiler support for complex part designators we have an alternative for the first form:

```
do i=1,3
  do j=1,3
    indx(i,j)%re = i
    indx(i,j)%im = j
  end do
end do
```

This doesn't really give us anything, but note that we can have the complex part of an array:

```
do i=1,3
  indx(i,:)%re = [(i,j=1,3)]
  indx(i,:)%im = [(j,j=1,3)]
end do
```

or

```
do i=1,3
  indx(i,:)%re = i  ! Using scalar to array assignment
  indx(i,:)%im = [(j,j=1,3)]
end do
```

And we could go all the way to

```
indx%re = RESHAPE([((i,i=1,3),j=1,3))],[3,3])
indx%im = RESHAPE([((j,i=1,3),j=1,3))],[3,3])
```

Again, that's all in the name of variety or for other applications.  There's even `spread` to consider in some of these.  But don't hate the person reviewing your code.

---

<sup>1</sup> That's [*constants* not *constant expresssions*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38969323).

Comment: tiny remark: as this is an in-depth look you could be paying respect to fortran's _column-major_ ordering, e.g. assign `indx(:,j)` instead of `indx(i,:)`. can never be to sure if compilers will optimize those loops.

Comment: The whole answer could do with a bit of tidying, and contiguous access would be worth a mention. I've been meaning to revise this a touch for a while, so let me see what I can do.