# Error with parentheses when assigning to complex variable

Tags: fortran

I have the following set of commands in my Fortran code:

```
COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(4,1) :: INSTATE_BASISSTATES    
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(:,:) = (0.0D0,0.0D0)
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(1,1) = ((1.0D0/SQRT(2)),0.0D0)
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(3,1) = ((1.0D0/SQRT(2)),0.0D0)
```

When I run/compile the program using gfortran on cygwin, I get the error

```
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(1,1) = (1.0D0/DREAL(SQRT(2.0D0)),0.0D0)
                                             1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)


INSTATE_BASISSTATES(3,1) = (1.0D0/DREAL(SQRT(2.0D0)),0.0D0)
                                             1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

What could be the issue? Aren't my brackets correct?

Comment: try changing `SQRT` by `DSQRT`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that is never a solution, I can't imagine a problem that would solve. DSQRT and other Dfunctions are of no use after FORTRAN 77 came almost 40 years ago.

Comment: next time I'll have the compiler ready to test instead of telling unchecked things.

Comment: BTW `DREAL` is not standard Fortran. I suggest you to not use it. Use just `REAL`. or possibly `DBLE`.

Answer (score 2):

On the right hand side of the assignment statement you are trying to use a complex literal constant.  However,

```
(1.0D0/DREAL(SQRT(2.0D0)),0.0D0)
```

isn't a valid form for such a constant.

For a complex literal, the real and imaginary components must be either named constants or literal constants.  `1.0D0/DREAL(SQRT(2.0D0))` is neither of those things.  For the line where you had no complaint, both components of `(0.0D0,0.0D0)` are literal constants.

As in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38970336) you could make a named constant with the value wanted and use that.  Alternatively, as you are just doing a boring assignment (which doesn't have various restrictions which apply to initialization, etc.,) you can use the `cmplx` intrinsic to return a complex value

```
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(1,1) = CMPLX(1.0D0/DREAL(SQRT(2.0D0)),0.0D0)
```

Here the real and imaginary components don't need to be constants.  You could even note that

```
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(1,1) = CMPLX(1.0D0/DREAL(SQRT(2.0D0)))
```

works just as well: if the imaginary component value isn't provided, the returned complex has imaginary component zero.

There is a slight complication, though.  `cmplx` by default returns a complex number with kind of the default real.  To return something matching `complex*16` (which isn't standard Fortran, but let's assume it corresponds to `double precision`) you'll need `CMPLX(..., [...], KIND=KIND(0d0)`) (or `KIND=KIND(INSTATE_BASISSTATES)`)

---

As a side note, as Vladimir F comments `dreal` isn't standard Fortran.  You could use `dble`, or `real` with a suitable kind number.  But we can also see that `sqrt(2d0)` already returns a double precision real, so even those are redundant: `1/sqrt(2d0)` has the same (mathematical) result as the original more cumbersome expression.  As do `2d0**(-0.5)` and `sqrt(2d0)/2`.

You could even replace the right hand side with

```
SQRT((5d-1,0))
```

as we see that `sqrt` also accepts a complex argument (in this case a complex literal constant).  This form also avoids the awkwardness of the `kind=` specifier: its value has kind as well as type of the argument.

Comment: I was lost in the parentheses and thought `DREAL` was used to get the real part of a complex number.

Comment: While `1/sqrt(2d0)` is mathematically equivalent to `sqrt(0.5D0)`, it is not necessarily numerically. There is a loss of precision due to the division which you don't have with `sqrt(0.5D0)`

Answer (score 1):

this is indeed "by design", one could define the constant of interest first and then use it in the initialization. For example:

```
COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(4,1) :: INSTATE_BASISSTATES
REAL*8, PARAMETER :: my_const = 1D0 / SQRT(2D0)
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(:,:) = (0.0D0,0.0D0)
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(1,1) = (my_const,0.0D0)
INSTATE_BASISSTATES(3,1) = (my_const,0.0D0)
```

However, the statement `REAL*8, PARAMETER :: my_const = 1D0 / SQRT(2D0)` seems to require at least Fortran2003 standard, otherwise, following error is produced `Elemental function as initialization expression with non-integer/non-character arguments`. One can specify the standard with gfortran with `-std=f2003` although it should be probably active by default.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how should I tweak my program in light of your suggestion. Please do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I still get the errors: `   REAL*8, PARAMETER :: my_const = 1.0D0 / SQRT(2D0)
   1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)` and `   REAL*8, PARAMETER :: my_const = 1.0D0 / SQRT(2D0)
   1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)` and `  INSTATE_BASISSTATES(1,1) = (my_const,0.0D0)
                                          1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)` and `  INSTATE_BASISSTATES(3,1) = (my_const,0.0D0)
                                          1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)`

Comment: I still get the errors:  `REAL*8, PARAMETER :: my_const = 1.0D0 / SQRT(2D0) 1 Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)` and `REAL*8, PARAMETER :: my_const = 1.0D0 / SQRT(2D0) 1 Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)` and `INSTATE_BASISSTATES(1,1) = (my_const,0.0D0) 1 Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)` and `INSTATE_BASISSTATES(3,1) = (my_const,0.0D0) 1 Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)`

Comment: And I get a 100 other errors when I use `std=f2003`

Comment: `Error: Non-numeric character in statement label`? you are using fixed source form?

Comment: Your code won't run with the flag `std=f2003` because `real*8` and  `complex*16` are not standard Fortran. The practice is ubiquitous, but `datatype*n` for types other than `character` was never part of any ISO Fortran standard. In fact, `character*n` is now declared obsolete. The standard committee encourages everyone to use `kind` and `len` parameters in the form of named integer constants.

Comment: Maybe we should forget the dogma on the standards for a while?

@J123 try indenting each line to column 7, as the first error says column-1 line-1 means you are not even staring out with a single valid character... Personally I would throw extra '()' in here: my_const = (1.0D0 / SQRT(2D0)) , and there use of '/' are generally historically helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

@J123 still hasn't answered the pressing question. Are you writing your code in fixed-form format with `.f` extension or free-form `.f90`? Also, what version of gfortran are you using? I've posted a complete fix below. You can foliate your arrays by direct assignment using named `parameter` constants, or as the return value of the intrinsic transformational function `cmplx`. Please note the liberal use of the `kind` parameter `wp` to control the floating-point precision.

```
program main

  use iso_fortran_env, only: &
       wp => REAL64, & ! Or REAL128 if your architecture supports it
       compiler_version, &
       compiler_options

  ! Explicit typing only
  implicit none

  ! Variable declarations
  complex(wp)          :: instate_basisstates(4,1)
  real (wp), parameter :: ZERO = 0 ! Assigning integers is safe
  real (wp), parameter :: SQRT2 = sqrt(2.0_wp)
  real (wp), parameter :: ONE_OVER_SQRT2 = 1.0_wp/SQRT2

  ! Executable statements
  instate_basisstates(:,:) = ZERO
  instate_basisstates(1,1) = (ONE_OVER_SQRT2, ZERO)
  instate_basisstates(3,1) = cmplx(1.0_wp/sqrt(2.0_wp), 0.0_wp, kind=wp)

  print '(/4a/)', &
       'This file was compiled using ', compiler_version(), &
       ' using the options ', compiler_options()

end program main
```

This yields:

```
This file was compiled using GCC version 6.1.1 20160802 using the options -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -O3 -Wall -std=f2008ts
```