# Assign complex array from real arrays in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have the following code modified from [Assigning variable number to complex array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247286/assigning-variable-number-to-complex-array)

```
program complex_array
    complex indx(3,3)
    integer i,j
    real   indx_re(3,3), indx_im(3,3)

    do i=1,3
      do j=1,3
       indx_re(i,j) = i + j           
       indx_im(i,j) = i - j
      end do
    end do    
    
    
    do i=1,3
      do j=1,3
       indx(i,j) = cmplx(indx_re(i,j),indx_im(i,j))               
       write(*,*) indx(i,j)
      end do
    end do
end
```

Is that possible to directly pass the value of complex array from real arrays, e.g., indx = (indx_re,  indx_im)?

Comment: Well, did you try to do `indx = (indx_re, indx_im)`?  What happen?  Note, the `cmplx` intrinsic function is elemental.  PS: your nested loops are backwards at least for filling `indx_re` anf `indx_im`.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried, it leads to ``` indx = (indx_re, indx_im) Error: Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant at (1) ``` by gfortran :(

Comment: Oops, ``` indx = cmplx(indx_re, indx_im) ``` seems work!

Comment: evets' comment  leads to the solution at least on gfortran, though the question is not the same as nor answered in the linked one, i.e., I asked about assign to the whole array directly, the linked one is per elements in loops.

Comment: Please see the second answer to that other question which mentions assignments to whole arrays/array sections using elemental `cmplx` and complex designators.